# gradle: Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when I use gradle(version 2.1 or 2.4) building Android Project, get the error below. I can not find `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1` in my files.

ERRORS:

```
config is set to BF688C717A5C3A69FE8CA522643C0A68
config is set to PRODUCT
vcode is set to 151
vname is set to 1.5.1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':XXXX'.

 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 

':yizhangtong:_rendepeng_lmDebugCompile'.

    Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1.

     Searched in the following locations:

.............

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 30.178 secs
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Apparently I am having similar issue with gradle 2.5

Comment: download android-sdk again(not update), could solve this problem.

Comment: Find sdk location and multidex path like this; "\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\multidex". You'll see versions already downloaded. just use last version. If still gets same error, check your sdk location.

Answer (score 18):

You need to install "Android Support Repository" from the Android SDK manager. (a.k.a `extra-android-m2repository` if installing from the command line)

```
**OR**
```

You need to install "Android Support Library(Obsolete)" from the Android SDK manager.

Comment: Worked for me (android GUI: Extras -> Android Support Repository)

Comment: I download "Android Support Repository", rebuild but still gets the error.

Comment: the same for me as for stackvoid

Comment: @stackvoid try second option.

Answer (score 8):

This issue exists in Android studio Beta versions
The only solution is to use

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

in project gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Installing both *Android Support Library* and *Local Maven Repository for Support Libraries* from the Android SDK manager (*Extras* section) fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Android SDK command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#download), type:

```
sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
```

The SDK manager will install the m2 repository

Answer (score -1):

try `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`

Comment: in build script, [compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'] existed. but still get the error

Comment: the same for me as for stackvoid

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by adding `google()` in `allprojects` node on top-level build.gradle file. Here is my top level file for reference

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
          mavenLocal()
          google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```