# Error while compiling multidex library after updating SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

I am pretty new to Android Studio.

I have converted my Eclipse project to Android Studio successfully. everything worked fine, until today I updated my SDK and suddenly it started giving me error

```
> Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
     https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
     https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
     file:/C:/Users/as/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
     file:/C:/Users/as/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
     file:/C:/Users/as/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.pom
     file:/C:/Users/as/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.jar
 Required by:
     ElalaSeller:app:unspecified
```

when I rebuild my project. it says

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
    Install Repository and sync project
    Show in File
    Show in Project Structure dialog
```

I checked Android support repository is installed.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

**Update :** I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283026/gradle-could-not-find-com-android-supportmultidex1-0-1) Question. most upvoted answer says install Android Support Repository. but in my case i already have installed it. you can see in screenshot i have uploaded. but still getting same error.

I have cleaned my project but still no change.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32469041/4596556).You should install `Android Support Repository`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gradle: Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283026/gradle-could-not-find-com-android-supportmultidex1-0-1)

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I already installed Android Support Repository you can see it in ss.

Comment: update your android studio and gradle version

Comment: @vrundpurohit Just `clean` your project and rebuild. Please update the question if any error you are getting during this process.

Comment: How about adding mavenCentral() for the repositories or try downgrade to com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar but same error. `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1`

Comment: What happen if you click on 'Install Repository and sync project'? Normally it does resolve your problem.

Comment: @AmadYus does nothing. just redirect to build.gradle.

Comment: @vrundpurohit Did you find a solution?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I decreased buildToolsVersion to 23.0.0 and it worked.