# Flutter Build failed with an exception. (Flutter build APK Error)

Tags: android, flutter, build, dependencies, apk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

  Could not find com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1.

  Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom
  - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom
  - https://www.jitpack.io/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom

  Required by:
  project :app

**and this error also when trying to fix this issue with multiple suggestion given by StackOverflow**

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1. Required by: project :app
```

**app\build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "co.demo.flutter"
        minSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
      signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'

}
```

**android\build\gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283026/gradle-could-not-find-com-android-supportmultidex1-0-1 check out this answers.

Comment: as I mention. now this error is showing:-                                                                               * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to change the gradle version in /android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

and Distribution Url

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Also Change your minSdkVersion to 21

Comment: done this changes but now this error is showing: Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/android/support/multidex/2.0.1/multidex-2.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Comment: Add android:exported="true" in AndroidManifest.xml inside activity tag...

Comment: still not working.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this in

android/app/build.gradle

lintOptions {
checkReleaseBuilds false
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qCt3.png)

Answer (score -1):

First:- Implement these changes

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Second is these:-

```
Add android:exported="true" in AndroidManifest.xml inside activity tag
```

And last is this:-

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
```